# I'm trying to make html2pdf after a form submitting

Tags: javascript, php, forms

when the form is empty my html2padf.js file works but when i fill my form and its submited only the form passes and the function does not work.

window.onload = function () {

```
document.getElementById("download")
    .addEventListener("click", () => {
        const invoice = this.document.getElementById("invoice");
        console.log(invoice);
        console.log(window);
        var opt = {
            margin: 0,
            filename: 'myfile.pdf',
            image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
            html2canvas: { scale: 1 },
            jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' }
        };
        html2pdf().from(invoice).set(opt).save();
    })
```

}

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: This function works perfect on any button exept on submit button on a form. The form is submitting but the html2pdf does not pass. shoud i give you something else?

Answer (score 0):

On submit your form will be cleared. You can add the value of the input field after the submit with:

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="subject" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['subject'])){echo $_POST['subject'];}?>">
</form>
```